# how to transcribe words into equations in php

Tags: php, math, equation

im trying change this word in Equation in php
can help me

```
$word="3W5D";
```

me try to change 3W5D to (3*$W)+(5*$D)=

is possible ?

Comment: What are the rules for the change?  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Where can you get the docs on this Equation syntax. Haven't seen anything like that yet. Or is a user made one?

Comment: is not way 3W5D to (3*$W)+(5*$D)= ????

Comment: my script show day like 3W5D my try show this word to 26Day

Comment: So is this 3 Weeks and 5 Days?

Comment: @yaghoobjamaladini, You are missing the point. The point is - where is the documentation for the syntax itself? How for example do you write `(3/$W)+(8*$D)` for exapmle? Or am I getting the syntax completly wrong?

Comment: yes 3 Weeks and 5 Days

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) are usually what you should use in such a case. It seems that you want to match patterns. Even though I don't know the exact rules of your pattern, here is a code sample that would do the job for the basic example you mentioned in your question. Just change the first argument of `preg_match` according to your exact needs:

```php
$word='3W5D';

preg_match('/((?P<week>\d+)W)?((?P<day>[0-6])D)?/', $word, $matches);

$coefWeek = 0;
$coefDay = 0;

if (array_key_exists('week', $matches)){
    $coefWeek = (int)$matches['week'];
}
if (array_key_exists('day', $matches)){
    $coefDay = (int)$matches['day'];
}

$res = $coefWeek*$W + $coefDay*$D;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match_all` and global variable variables:

```
<?php
$W = 7; $D = 4; // I wouldn't uppercase my variables, but that's another story
function weirdParse($str){
  if(preg_match_all('/\d+|\D+/', $str, $m)){
    $a = $m[0];
    global ${$a[1]}, ${$a[3]};
    return $a[0]*${$a[1]}+$a[2]*${$a[3]};
  }
  return false;
}
$test = weirdParse('3W5D');
echo $test;
?>
```